# Begin to use EDMX Immediately

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I have create a table and create edmx file, and I create a Stored Procedure that return a single row (select by primary key), and I want the edmx to have a function that calls that SP and return a type. How to do it, please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the entity model in design mode. Right click, choose "add", choose "Function import". Now in the dialog you give the procedure a name and choose the procedure from the drop down.

However, if you already have the table in your entity model you can select a single row based on primary key quite easily:

```
var objectRepresentingSingleRow = yourDataContext.theTable.First(t => t.Id == someId);
```

Comment: Hi Klaus, however it return type ObjectResult<MyType> instead of MyType directly, how to access the returned object? I don't want to use the context.table.First

Comment: @John, there is no way that the framework can know that your query will only return one row. Therefore, to access the object you will need to do `objectResult.First()` where `objectResult` is of type `ObjectResult<MyType>`